# Traducir este código a java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando traducir este código a java pero de momento no lo consegui, el código es:

```
string value = "";
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
            {
                if (reader.BaseStream.Length > 1024)
                {
                    reader.BaseStream.Seek(-1024, SeekOrigin.End);

                }
                value = reader.ReadToEnd();


            }


            /*using (var reader = new StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
            {
                if (reader.BaseStream.Length > 1024)
                {
                    reader.BaseStream.Seek(-1024, SeekOrigin.End);

                }
                value = reader.ReadToEnd();


            }
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
            */

            Match regex = Regex.Match(value, "-ip-(.*?)-ip--port-(.*?)-port--password-(.*?)-password-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            // y el puerto
            if (regex.Success) // Si se encontro algo ...
            {
                pool = regex.Groups[1].Value; // Guardamos la IP encontrada en la variable "ip"
                email = regex.Groups[2].Value; // Guardamos el puerto encontrado en la variable "port"
                password = regex.Groups[3].Value;
            }
```

Intente con algun traductor o algo. pero tampoco funciono.

```
string value = "";
var reader = new StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
,SeekOrigin.End;
UnknownUnknownvalue = reader.ReadToEnd();
UnknownMatch regex = Regex.Match(value, "-ip-(.*?)-ip--port-(.*?)-port--password-(.*?)-password-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
//  y el puerto
if (regex.Success) {
    pool = regex.Groups[1].Value;
    //  Guardamos la IP encontrada en la variable "ip"
    email = regex.Groups[2].Value;
    //  Guardamos el puerto encontrado en la variable "port"
    password = regex.Groups[3].Value;
}
```

Pero sigue sin ser funcional alguna idea a que se deba o como adaptarlo?

Comment: No sabía que Sergio Ramos estudia programación xD.

Comment: @Sergio Ramos podrías explicar un pocos mas a q te refieres con la traducción

Comment: estaba intentando hacer este código en c# funcional en java pero no consigo leer el ultimo byte correctamente en java.